# XML-less configuration for struts1

Tags: struts-1

A very bad news: I have to use struts 1.x in my projects.

There are so many XML configuration for struts1, which is so boring. Is there any way to avoid them? For example, struts plugins, annotations, or others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within the Struts project itself.

There's [Struts Annotations](http://code.google.com/p/struts-annotations/), which I've not used.

In the olden days, [XDoclet's Struts tags](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/tags/apache-tags.html#@struts_Tag_Reference) was the norm for XML-less config.

If neither of those strike your fancy, simply generating an XML config programmatically via a DSL or builder patter works.